# Temporizar un proceso en bash

Tags: bash, proceso

quisiera saber si es posible ejecutar un comando en un script en bash durante un tiempo concreto y se cancele automáticamente cuando se acabe ese tiempo como si hubiera pulsado ctrl+c y continúe a la siguiente tarea el script.

ejemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo netdiscover >> archivo.txt
sleep 
sudo netdiscover >> archivo2.txt
sleep
```

No se si se entiende lo que busco, necesito que se pare el proceso por ejemplo a los 30 segundos para que se genere un archivo con la información y vuelva a arrancar otra vez para generarme otro archivo y después con calma poder revisar toda la información.

Comment: La sentencia `sleep` es válida, tan sólo añádele el número de segundos que quieres, como por ejemplo `sleep 30` para 30 segundos de inactividad en el script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes enviar la señal de kill al proceso netdiscover y seguiría con las siguientes instrucciones de bash.
Es decir

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo netdiscover >> archivo.txt &
sleep 10 #El tiempo que necesites estar corriendo netdiscover
killall netdiscover
sudo netdiscover >> archivo2.txt &
sleep 10 #El tiempo que necesites estar corriendo netdiscover
```

Comment: No funciono, cuando utilizo ctrl+c se guarda toda la información pero al matar el proceso con killall o no se guarda nada o casi nada :(

Comment: Entonces puedes averiguar el pid de netdiscover con pidof
$pid = pidof netdiscover
Y luego utilizar la señal 2 de kill que es como un ctrl+c 
kill -2 $pid

    SIGINT (2) - Interrupt from keyboard (like CTRL+C)